# How to run a Concurrent thread on javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

**how to insert concurrent thread into java fx codes below, so that the Graphic User Interface (GUI) can display the bid number, lap time and lap count.**

here are my codes:

napfa_running_reader.java

```
package napfa_running_reader;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import com.thingmagic.*;
import java.util.Hashtable; // Added by Darren
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class Napfa_Running_Reader extends Application {

    private static DbConnect db = new DbConnect();
    private static Reader r = null;
    private static String argv [] = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextArea ta = new TextArea();
        ta.setEditable(false);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Stop Reader");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // System.out.println("Program Terminated!");
                ta.appendText("Program Terminated!\n");
                r.destroy();
                //System.exit(0); //Kill whole program
            }
        });

        VBox vb = new VBox();       
        vb.getChildren().addAll(ta, btn);
        vb.setSpacing(10);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vb);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("NAPFA Lap Timing Monitor");  //Change the window title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        

        int nextarg = 0;
        boolean trace = false;
        int[] antennaList = null;

        if (argv.length < 1) {
            usage();
        }

        if (argv[nextarg].equals("-v")) {
            trace = true;
            nextarg++;
        }

        // Create Reader object, connecting to physical device
        try {
            TagReadData[] tagReads;
            String readerURI = argv[nextarg];
            nextarg++;

            for (; nextarg < argv.length; nextarg++) {
                String arg = argv[nextarg];
                if (arg.equalsIgnoreCase("--ant")) {
                    if (antennaList != null) {
                        System.out.println("Duplicate argument: --ant specified more than once");
                        usage();
                    }
                    antennaList = parseAntennaList(argv, nextarg);
                    nextarg++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Argument " + argv[nextarg] + " is not recognised");
                    usage();
                }
            }
            readerURI = readerURI.substring(9);
            r = Reader.create(readerURI);
            if (trace) {
                setTrace(r, new String[]{"on"});
            }
            r.connect();
            if (Reader.Region.UNSPEC == (Reader.Region) r.paramGet("/reader/region/id")) {
                Reader.Region[] supportedRegions = (Reader.Region[]) r.paramGet(TMConstants.TMR_PARAM_REGION_SUPPORTEDREGIONS);
                if (supportedRegions.length < 1) {
                    throw new Exception("Reader doesn't support any regions");
                } else {
                    r.paramSet("/reader/region/id", supportedRegions[0]);
                }
            }

            String model = r.paramGet("/reader/version/model").toString();
            if ((model.equalsIgnoreCase("M6e Micro") || model.equalsIgnoreCase("M6e Nano")) && antennaList == null) {
                System.out.println("Module doesn't has antenna detection support, please provide antenna list");
                r.destroy();
                usage();
            }

            SimpleReadPlan plan = new SimpleReadPlan(antennaList, TagProtocol.GEN2, null, null, 1000);
            r.paramSet(TMConstants.TMR_PARAM_READ_PLAN, plan);

            Hashtable<String, Tag> ht = new Hashtable<String, Tag>();

            while (true) {
                // Read tags
                tagReads = r.read(500);
                // Print tag reads
                for (TagReadData tr : tagReads) {
                   String tagID = tr.toString().substring(4, 28);                    
                   ta.appendText("Info Received: " + tr.toString() + "\n");
                   ta.appendText("Tag ID Found: " + tagID + "\n");
                   ta.appendText("Bid Number: " + db.getBidNo(tagID) + "\n");

                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (!ht.containsKey(tagID)) {
                        ht.put(tagID, new Tag(currentTime));
                    } else {
                        long duration = currentTime - ht.get(tagID).getPrevTiming();

                        if ((duration / 1000) > 35 && ht.get(tagID).getNoOfLaps() < 6) {
                                ht.get(tagID).setPrevTime(currentTime);
                                ht.get(tagID).addTiming(duration + ht.get(tagID).getLatestLapTiming());
                        } 
                    }

                        ta.appendText("No. of Laps: " + ht.get(tagID).getNoOfLaps() + "\n");
                        ta.appendText(ht.get(tagID).displayLapTimings() + "\n");  

                    if (ht.get(tagID).getNoOfLaps() == 6 && !ht.get(tagID).isRunCompleted() && ht.containsKey(tagID)) {
                        ta.appendText(tagID + " Run Completed" + "\n");

                        db.updateLapTimings(ht.get(tagID), tagID);                        
                        ht.get(tagID).setRunCompleted();                       
                    }               
                }
            }

        } catch (ReaderException re) {
            System.out.println("Reader Exception : " + re.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception re) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + re.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void usage() {
        System.out.printf("Usage: Please provide valid arguments, such as:\n"
                + "  (URI: 'tmr:///COM1 --ant 1,2' or 'tmr://astra-2100d3/ --ant 1,2' "
                + "or 'tmr:///dev/ttyS0 --ant 1,2')\n\n");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public void setTrace(Reader r, String args[]) {
        if (args[0].toLowerCase().equals("on")) {
            r.addTransportListener(r.simpleTransportListener);
        }
    }

    public int[] parseAntennaList(String[] args, int argPosition) {
        int[] antennaList = null;
        try {
            String argument = args[argPosition + 1];
            String[] antennas = argument.split(",");
            int i = 0;
            antennaList = new int[antennas.length];
            for (String ant : antennas) {
                antennaList[i] = Integer.parseInt(ant);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            System.out.println("Missing argument after " + args[argPosition]);
            usage();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid argument at position " + (argPosition + 1) + ". " + ex.getMessage());
            usage();
        }
        return antennaList;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        argv = args;
        launch(args);       
    }

}
```

Tag.java

```
package napfa_running_reader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class Tag {
    private ArrayList<Long> timings;
    private long prevTime;
    private boolean runCompleted;

    public Tag(long prevTime) {
        this.timings = new ArrayList<Long>();
        this.prevTime = prevTime;
        this.runCompleted = false;
    }

    //Accessor Methods
    public long getPrevTiming() {
        return this.prevTime;
    }

    public int getNoOfLaps() {
        return this.timings.size();
    }

    public long getLatestLapTiming() {
        return (this.timings.size() == 0) ? 0L : this.timings.get(this.timings.size() - 1);
    }

    public boolean isRunCompleted() 
    {
        return this.runCompleted;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTimings()
    {
        ArrayList <String> list_of_timings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(long timing : this.timings)
        {
            list_of_timings.add(getTimeString(timing));
        }

        return list_of_timings;
    }

    public String displayLapTimings() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 1;

        for (long timing : this.timings) {
            sb.append("Lap " + count + ":" + getTimeString(timing));
            sb.append("\n");
            count++;
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    //Mutator Methods
    public void addTiming(long timing) {
        this.timings.add(timing);
    }

    public void setPrevTime(long prevTime) {
        this.prevTime = prevTime;
    }

    public void setRunCompleted() 
    {
        this.runCompleted = true;
    }

    //Other Methods
    private String getTimeString(long timing) {
        long second = (timing / 1000) % 60;
        long minute = (timing / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        long hour = (timing / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

        String timeStr = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);

        return timeStr;
    }
}
```

DbConnect.java

```
package napfa_running_reader;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class DbConnect {

    private Connection conn = null;
    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/napfa_test_system";

    private void openConn()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private void closeConn()
    {
      try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }  
    }

    public String getBidNo(String tagID)
    {
       String bidNo = "";

       try{
           openConn();

           String query = "SELECT bid_number from bid_number_rfid_info_table WHERE rfid_number = ?";
           PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
           stmt.setString(1, tagID);
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
           rs.next();
           bidNo = rs.getString("bid_number");

           closeConn();

       } catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }

        return bidNo;
    }

    public void updateLapTimings(Tag tagItem, String tagID) 
    {
        try {
            openConn();

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();
            String today = dateFormat.format(date);

            ArrayList<String> list_of_timings = tagItem.getTimings();
            String query = "UPDATE napfa_running_result_info_table SET lap1_time = ?, lap2_time = ?, lap3_time = ?, " + 
                            "lap4_time = ?, lap5_time = ?, lap6_time = ?, rfid_number = ? WHERE created_date = ? AND bid_number = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            //Update Lap Timings
            stmt.setString(1, list_of_timings.get(0));
            stmt.setString(2, list_of_timings.get(1));
            stmt.setString(3, list_of_timings.get(2));
            stmt.setString(4, list_of_timings.get(3));
            stmt.setString(5, list_of_timings.get(4));
            stmt.setString(6, list_of_timings.get(5));

            //Update rfid_number, created_date, bid_number
            stmt.setString(7, tagID);
            stmt.setString(8, today);
            stmt.setString(9, getBidNo(tagID));

            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            closeConn();
        }  catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what your separate task is, and how you start it? In general you will probably want a [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html).

Comment: what service are you mentioning?

Comment: It is a link to a class.

Comment: which class are u refering

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do and perhaps you could demonstrate it with a program which is [smaller and still complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or describe it better.  If you want to understand concurrency in JavaFX, read the the [JavaFX concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).